# realm warning: Unclosed files for the types?

Tags: android, realm

I am developing cv and I have used realm database but I am getting following error

> public class KitabSawti extends RealmObject {
>          ^ warning: Unclosed files for the types '[io.realm.activity_drawer_navigation_com_kitabsawticlone_Pojo_KitabSawtiRealmProxy]';
>   these types will not undergo annotation processing 1 error 1 warning

below My Java class

```
public class KitabSawti extends RealmObject {
        @SerializedName("Introduction")
        @Expose
        private RealmList<Introduction> introduction = null;
        @SerializedName("Education")
        @Expose
        private List<Education> education = null;
        @SerializedName("Work")
        @Expose
        private List<Work> work = null;
        @SerializedName("Skills")
        @Expose
        private List<Skill> skills = null;
        @SerializedName("Contact")
        @Expose
        private List<Contact> contact = null;

        public RealmList<Introduction> getIntroduction() {
            return introduction;
        }

        public void setIntroduction(RealmList<Introduction> introduction) {
            this.introduction = introduction;
        }

        public List<Education> getEducation() {
            return education;
        }

        public void setEducation(List<Education> education) {
            this.education = education;
        }

        public List<Work> getWork() {
            return work;
        }

        public void setWork(List<Work> work) {
            this.work = work;
        }

        public List<Skill> getSkills() {
            return skills;
        }

        public void setSkills(List<Skill> skills) {
            this.skills = skills;
        }

        public List<Contact> getContact() {
            return contact;
        }

        public void setContact(List<Contact> contact) {
            this.contact = contact;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is this error happening?

Answer (score 1):

Following might help.

1. If `List<Education>, List<Work>, List<Skill>, List<Contact>` are relationships where Education, Work, Skill and Contact are RealmObjects, you may need to use RealmList<> for each of them
2. In case they are not RealmObjects, you might have to add @Ignore above all these attributes to instruct realm to ignore trying to persist them.